Why is text not showing up on my Tkinter window?
So, I was trying to learn tkinter, I tried running the app, but this is what came up:

What could be the problem to this? I tried the same thing in light mode, but again, showed a blank window:

How do I solve this problem? I use MacOS Sonoma, with Python 3.9.6, and it came pre-installed. Here's the code btw:
# Imports
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Main App
app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("720x540")
app.title("App Test")

label = ttk.Label(master = app, text = "Hello, World!")
label.pack()

app.mainloop()                              

I tried reinstalling tkinter (cuz it said on some stackoverflow question), but this is what came up:
% pip3 uninstall tkinter
WARNING: Skipping tkinter as it is not installed.

Plus, it's said tkinter is not installed, even though it shows a window when i run it

See Bryan's comment in this question tkinter-window-is-empty-on-macos

There are some known issues with tkinter on Mac OS. I have an answer here that might help!

As I already explained in the Staging Ground, you cannot use Pip to install or uninstall Tkinter. pip3 is Pip and Pip has nothing to do with the problem. Pip is only for third-party libraries. Tkinter comes with Python.

Updating python version to Python 3.11.4 works for me
